# Rails- is there a method that is essentially `map.find` for arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-7

Looking for a method that will iterate through a list and return the first *transformed* value.
Essentially:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].magic { |i| 
  puts "Checking #{i}"
  i ** 2 if i > 2 
}
Checking 1
Checking 2
Checking 3
#=> 9
```

The goal here being that it works like `find` and stops iterating through the list after getting the first return. (Notice it never checks `4`) but also returns the value from the block. (Returns `9` instead of `3`)

The issue here is that the block is performing some complex logic, so I don't want to map over the entire array, but I also want to use the value of said logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the loop with a desired return value. Is this what you are looking for?

```rb
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array.map { |element| break element ** 2 if element > 2 }
# returns 9
```

Comment: Not quite as elegant as I was hoping, and you need special functionality to handle no matched, but essentially does what I need! Thank you!

Comment: You can map the array with the result object if you want. This way it will return the result object if it is not break. This way you may return a default value if there is no match but still it won't be elegant.